# How to use import library from build dir in cmake?

Tags: cmake, import-libraries

For example I have 2 independent(! and they should be independent!) build tasks.

First task build the library.

Second task build binary that should use libary from the first task.
I dont need any type of install library, instead I just need to use library in build tree that was build by first task.

So in the cmake script of the library I add followed string:

```
...
export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE MyLibConfig.cmake)
...
```

Then I think in binary cmake script I should do somehow import and additionally pass the path to the librarys MyLibConfig.cmake as a command line parameter

There are a lot if info about export, but no one info how to do import.

Could smbody explain?

PS: but please explain by own words, don`t give just a link - I read a lot of them and all it is unclear and does not works :(

**UPD3**:
Ok, lets try to make some simple example.

The library consist of 3 files

```
// MyLib.h
#pragma once

int MyFunc();

//------------------------------------
// MyLib.cpp
#include "MyLib.h"

int MyFunc()
{
    return 5;
}
```

And the cmake-file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)
project (MyLib)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")   # binaries
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")   # static lib
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")   # shared lib

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} MyLib.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..>
)

export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE MyLibConfig.cmake)
```

The binary project consist of 2 files

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)
project (MyBin)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")   # binaries
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")   # static lib
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")   # shared lib

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(MyLib REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC MyLib)
```

And the .cpp-file

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <MyLib.h>

int main()
{
    int k = MyFunc();
    ++k;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I launch cmake for binary build with MyLib_DIR variable path to generated MyLibConfig.cmake

CMake finished work without any errors, but I receive compilation error

```
Main.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MyLib.h': No such file or directory
```

What and how I should to fix?

Comment: In CMake "importing" is performed with [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) command. In your case it could be `find_package(MyLib REQUIRED)` call. By setting `MyLib_DIR` variable, you may tell CMake which exact directory contains `MyLibConfig.cmake` file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, oh ok, now cmake could generate cache. But how to use *.h-files of MyLib? Now it couldnt be reached from binary project. Look please at the update of the initial post for details.

Comment: You probably want to read CMake documentation about packaging: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages. The documentation describes an example about packaging existing CMake project for being accessible in other CMake projects. While they mainly explain packaging of installation tree  (with `install(EXPORT)`), a packaging of build tree (with `export()`) uses similar concepts. BTW, the example also uses `export(EXPORT)` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I read your link but it is still unclear what I should to do. As you note - the cmake team write documentation only for installation - but it is very rarely step in development and in real life it always separate step (sometimes with separate team). Why cmake team avoid all time explanation of usual work when developer have a set of libs and binaries that builds with different projects - I dont know. Look please on Upd2. I try to write simple example using your link but have an error. Could you help to say how to fix it?

Comment: "But it is have error on line export." - What **exact error message** do you get?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I see "export Export set "MyLib" not found." In your link there are a previous installation step present - maybe it have influence. But I dont need installation and dont know how it should be in my case.

Comment: Hm, as far as I understand documentation, `export(EXPORT)` signature is for export set defined in `install(TARGETS .. EXPORT)` calls. Without installing, you may use `export(TARGETS)` signature.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I rewrite upd. Please look at it. I back to compilation error - the binary didnt see the libraryes headers files :(

Comment: Config file created by `export(TARGETS)` doesn't provide variables like `MyLib_INCLUDE_DIR` or `MyLib_LIBRARIES`. Instead, it provides IMPORTED **target** (`MyLib` in your case). Linking with that target should give include directories too: `target_link_libraries(MyBin MyLib)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I remove in upd two lines with MyLib_INCLUDE_DIR and MyLib_LIBRARIES and add "target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC MyLib)" after find package, but it doest helps. Do you have any idea what should I do? I think - is it ever posible to use cmake as I want? Maybe it works only in primitive mode when all should be added only as subdirectory? What do you think about it?